# NextAuth() return value in next-auth v4

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using next-auth v4 and I'd like to destructure the object returned by NextAuth() as follows:

```
 export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signOut,
  signIn,
} = NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db) as Adapter,
  providers: [
    Github({
      clientId: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
});
```

However, when I'm using v4 (4.24.7) of next-auth, all the destructured values are undefined. Using v5 (beta15) works fine.
I've checked the [documentation](https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/prisma?_gl=1*ajo4e8*_gcl_au*MjAwMDQ1ODc3MS4xNzEwMTMxOTM5LjQ1NjA1NjU3Ny4xNzEwNzkyNTQ3LjE3MTA3OTI1NDY.) for using the prisma adapter and the example there looks pretty much the same. (besides that they're using a different provider)

What could cause the issue with next-auth v4 ?

Comment: How does the value of `NextAuth({...........})` look like ? may be it doesn't have those properties in it ..

Comment: In v5, an object is returned:

  handlers: { GET: [Function: httpHandler], POST: [Function: httpHandler] },
  auth: [Function (anonymous)],
  signIn: [Function: signIn],
  signOut: [Function: signOut],
  unstable_update: [Function: unstable_update]
} 

In v4 it's a promise. I'm wondering how can it work according the documentation with v4 .

Comment: so obviously it doesn't work until it (the promise)  is fulfilled right ...